# How do I change the timezone of my db2 service on Bluemix

Tags: timezone, db2, cloud, ibm-cloud

The title should say it all. I have a service on Bluemix. From what I see there are two regions I can set up an application - US South or UK. Because it was set up quite some time ago when and it grew substantially, I don't want to move my service from US South to UK or change all of my time related queries either. Is there a way I could change the timezone of my DB2 service to match my current timezone / region (Irish Summer Time) without moving the whole application "overseas"?

Answer (score 0):

A DB2 instance (including currently both "SQL Database" and "dashDB" services on Bluemix) takes its timezone setting from the underlying operating system. Unless there is an option to select the timezone when you provision either service (which, in my opinion, there must be), I'm afraid you'll have to move the service physically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting for timezone for Bluemix dashDB instances, users, tables or columns.
There is also no information on timezone setting in Web GUI; you must query the DB.

MAJOR FAIL

Comment: You can always submit suggestions for improvement through the IBM Bluemix Ideas site below. I will submit a suggestion based on this thread.          https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas